# Finding preimage of a function

Tags: analysis

Let $\{r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n\}$ be an enumeration of the set of rational numbers and $(y_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ which converges to $y_0\in \mathbb{R}$. Define $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align*}
f(y)=\begin{cases}
y_n,\quad y=r_n\quad for\,some\,n\in \mathbb{N}\\
y_0, \quad y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Suppose $G\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is an open set. I want to find $f^{-1}(G)$.
I have tried but I am not sure with my answer, especially for Case 2 and Case 4. Here is my attempt.

1. If $\:y_n, y_0\in G$, then $f^{-1}(G)=\mathbb{R}$,
2. If $\:y_n\in G$ and $y_0\notin G$, then $f^{-1}(G)=\{r_n\}$, for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
3. If $\:y_n, y_0\notin G$, then $f^{-1}(G)=\emptyset$,
4. If $\:y_n\notin G$ and $y_0\in G$. It will be impossible because $y_n\in G^c$ with $G^c$ closed. Since $y_n \to y_0$ and $G^c$ closed, then $y_0$ must be contained in $G^c$. Therefore, $f^{-1}(G)=\emptyset$,

Is there any mistake?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your definition of $f$ makes no sense:  $x$ appears nowhere on the right.

Comment: @Randall I am sorry, it is a typo, I mean $f(y)$. I have edited it.

Comment: Seems correct, except you need to explain the difference wrt where some $y_i \in G$ and other $y_j \not\in G$